# Revision books for experienced developers

Tags: oop, architecture

When asked yesterday, I couldnt explain the difference between an abstract class and interface, even though I understand the difference (couldn't get the right normal-human-language words out). I also forgot the formal definition of a 3-tier architecture, even though I use the concept every day.

Is there a book or site that a complete read-through of would be the same as a refresher-course for experienced developers? In other words: "here are most of the things you should know, with a brief definition for each"?

Obviously, this would go out of date relatively quickly, but I mean I want one mainly with core OO and architectural design concepts.

Comment: look at this article for a discussion on interface and inheritance http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2003/jw-0801-toolbox.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you should refer to [Wikipedia](http://wikipedia.org/) for short explanations and definitions. The kind of information you are looking for won't be found in the books for experienced developers. You should rather search the books for beginners. And that is if you really need only the brief definition.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft MSDN is the best source for this kind of information.

But, this kind of information is something which should be built own our own based on own experience and interviews faced like yours. No book publishes this kind of ready reckoner as far as I know. Also, the wording you use to explain technical concepts depends totally on your understanding and your point of view, again based on how clear you are with that concept. BUT, gathering such information and publishing it to help your friends is a good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

I think for enterprise architecture and patterns you must read Addisson Wesley "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture" by Martin Fowler

Answer (score 0):

Do you guys think it would be worth hosting a small website with exactly this on it? Important/common terms and practices and a brief definition of each, as well as a link to a more in-depth article?